# Checking for availability of network disk on mac

Tags: macos, rsync, mount

I'm creating myself a script to automate the backing up of certain directories on my mac to an airdisk (usb disk on my airport extreme).

I was reading up about rsync. It seems that if the airdisk isn't mounted, rsync creates the directory in "/Volumes/the name of the disk".

This could fill up my hard drive and it isn't supposed to make the backup on my local drive.
Therefore I want to check if the mounted drive is available before I start the rsync command.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks everyone.
i solved it with this: if [ -f /Volumes/AirDisk/foo.txt ];

Answer (score 3):

I would check to see if a file located in the mount exists. As long as you mount the disk in the same location each time, this should work.

```
if [ -f /Volumes/AirDisk/foo.txt ];
then
   echo "AirDisk mounted. Starting backup"
   #Put backup script here
else
   echo "File does not exists"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: i'm no bash guru, but it seems that you provide a parameter -f in the if statement without an actual command. or is that the way it's done?

Comment: @NightWalker: `[` is actually a command (a synonym for `test`), it just doesn't look like one.

Comment: thanks for the information.  i just have 1 more question.  the script seems to fail on the exit(1) command: /perform_backup.script: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
./perform_backup.script: line 8: `   exit(1)'

Comment: @NightWalker: The parentheses shouldn't be there; line 8 should just be `exit 1`

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the exit issue.

Comment: Can’t you check `-d /Volumes/AirDisk` instead?

Comment: Maybe. He was said that if /Volumes/Airdisk wasn't mounted then rsync would create that directory. If somehow rsync ran earlier and created the folder then it would detect that directory. You SHOULD be able to do it with `-d` but I believe it is safer to detect the file.

Comment: But if `rsync` created the folder than it could’ve created the file as well — depending on exactly what `rsync` is syncing, anyway. Maybe a combination of `mount`, `cut`, `grep` is more robust.